# how use shingle token elasticsearch begin from string

Tags: elasticsearch

I want use Shingle token to analyze the string "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog" into:

1.The

2.The quick

...

n. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog

I need help.
Thanks.

Comment: Please include the code or configuration that you have tried already in your question to receive a better response to your question.

Answer (score 0):

## Answer #1. The Shingle Filter & the Predicate Token Filter

I feel certain you can query only tokens have position 0 with the shingle filter. All you have to do is add the predicate_token_filter

Mapping

```
PUT /edge_shingles/
{
    "settings": {
        "max_shingle_diff" : 10,
        "analysis": {
            "analyzer": {
                "whitespace_shingle_analyzer": {
                    "tokenizer": "whitespace",
                    "filter": [
                        "shingle_filter",
                        "edge_shingle_filter"
                    ]
                }
            },
            "filter": {
                "shingle_filter": {
                    "type": "shingle",
                    "min_shingle_size": 2,
                    "max_shingle_size": 4,
                    "output_unigrams": true
                },
                "edge_shingle_filter": {
                    "type": "predicate_token_filter",
                    "script": {
                        "source": """
                            token.position == 0;
                        """
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "mappings": {
        "properties": {
            "text": {
                "type": "text",
                "analyzer": "whitespace_shingle_analyzer"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Term vectors

```
{
    "term_vectors" : {
        "text" : {
            "terms" : {
                "The" : {
                    "term_freq" : 1
                },
                "The quick" : {
                    "term_freq" : 1
                },
                "The quick brown" : {
                    "term_freq" : 1
                },
                "The quick brown fox" : {
                    "term_freq" : 1
                },
                "The quick brown fox jumps" : {
                    "term_freq" : 1
                },
                "The quick brown fox jumps over" : {
                    "term_freq" : 1
                },
                "The quick brown fox jumps over the" : {
                    "term_freq" : 1
                },
                "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy" : {
                    "term_freq" : 1
                },
                "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog" : {
                    "term_freq" : 1
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I changed the max_shingle_diff shingle filter restrictions in the mapping

Answer (score 0):

## Answer #2. Pure Scripting

My original answer implied pure scripting for tokenization and edge shingle generation

Mapping

```
PUT /edge_shingles_scripted
{
    "mappings": {
        "properties": {
            "text": {
                "type": "text",
                "fielddata": true, 
                "analyzer": "whitespace"
            },
            "edge_shingles": {
                "type": "text",
                "analyzer": "keyword"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Pure scripted update by query with tokenization and edge shingle generation

```
POST /edge_shingles_scripted/_update_by_query
{
    "query": {
        "match_all": {
        }
    },
    "script": {
        "source": """
            List tokenize(def text, def delimiter) {
                List terms = new LinkedList();
                int offset = 0;
                int next = 0;

                while ((next = text.indexOf(delimiter, offset)) != -1) {
                    terms.add(text.substring(offset, next));
                    offset = next + 1;
                }
                terms.add(text.substring(offset, text.length()));
                return terms;
            }
            
            List edgeShingle(List terms, def delimiter, def minShingleSize, def maxShingleSize) {
                List edgeShingles = new LinkedList();
                StringBuilder edgeShingledTerm = new StringBuilder();
                
                for (int i = 0; i < terms.size(); i++) {
                    edgeShingledTerm.append(terms[i]).append(delimiter);
                    if ((i >= minShingleSize - 1) &&
                            (i <= maxShingleSize - 1)) {
                        edgeShingles.add(edgeShingledTerm.toString().trim());
                    }
                }

                return edgeShingles;
            }
            
            def text = ctx._source.text;
            List terms = tokenize(text, params.text_delimiter);
            List edgeShingles = edgeShingle(terms, params.term_delimiter, params.min_shingle_size, params.max_shingle_size);
            
            ctx._source.edge_shingles = edgeShingles;
        """,
        "params": {
            "min_shingle_size": 1,
            "max_shingle_size": 14,
            "text_delimiter": " ",
            "term_delimiter": " "
        }
    }
}
```

Term vectors

```
{
    "term_vectors" : {
        "edge_shingles" : {
            "terms" : {
                "The" : {
                    "term_freq" : 1
                },
                "The quick" : {
                    "term_freq" : 1
                },
                "The quick brown" : {
                    "term_freq" : 1
                },
                "The quick brown fox" : {
                    "term_freq" : 1
                },
                "The quick brown fox jumps" : {
                    "term_freq" : 1
                },
                "The quick brown fox jumps over" : {
                    "term_freq" : 1
                },
                "The quick brown fox jumps over the" : {
                    "term_freq" : 1
                },
                "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy" : {
                    "term_freq" : 1
                },
                "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog" : {
                    "term_freq" : 1
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

By using the following index settings where we create a custom analyzer with a shingle token filter, you'll be able to generate the terms you're expecting:

```
curl -XPUT localhost:9200/your_index -d '{
  "settings": {
    "index": {
      "number_of_shards": "5",
      "number_of_replicas": "1",
      "analysis": {
        "analyzer": {
          "my_shingles": {
            "tokenizer": "standard",
            "filter": [
              "shingles"
            ]
          }
        },
        "filter": {
          "shingles": {
            "type": "shingle",
            "min_shingle_size": 2,
            "max_shingle_size": 10
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "your_type": {
      "properties": {
        "field": {
          "type": "string",
          "analyzer": "my_shingles"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}'
```

Then, we can ask the `_analyze` endpoint to show how it would tokenize your sentence:

```
 curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/your_index/_analyze?analyzer=my_shingles&pretty' -d 'The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog'
```

The response will be

```
{
  "tokens" : [ {
    "token" : "The",
    "start_offset" : 0,
    "end_offset" : 3,
    "type" : "<ALPHANUM>",
    "position" : 1
  }, {
    "token" : "The quick",
    "start_offset" : 0,
    "end_offset" : 9,
    "type" : "shingle",
    "position" : 1
  }, {
    "token" : "The quick brown",
    "start_offset" : 0,
    "end_offset" : 15,
    "type" : "shingle",
    "position" : 1
  }, {
    "token" : "The quick brown fox",
    "start_offset" : 0,
    "end_offset" : 19,
    "type" : "shingle",
    "position" : 1
  }, {
    "token" : "The quick brown fox jumps",
    "start_offset" : 0,
    "end_offset" : 25,
    "type" : "shingle",
    "position" : 1
  }, {
    "token" : "The quick brown fox jumps over",
    "start_offset" : 0,
    "end_offset" : 30,
    "type" : "shingle",
    "position" : 1
  }, {
    "token" : "The quick brown fox jumps over the",
    "start_offset" : 0,
    "end_offset" : 34,
    "type" : "shingle",
    "position" : 1
  }, {
    "token" : "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy",
    "start_offset" : 0,
    "end_offset" : 39,
    "type" : "shingle",
    "position" : 1
  }, {
    "token" : "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog",
    "start_offset" : 0,
    "end_offset" : 43,
    "type" : "shingle",
    "position" : 1
  }, {
  ...
```

You'll also note that there will be a lot more shingles generated, but the ones above do match your expectations.

Comment: Thanks, but i want query only tokens have position 1.

Comment: Ok, that wasn't explicit. Then I'm not certain that you can achieve what you expect with shingles, unfortunately.